# Use VBA to loop through email recipients and check against an array of domains

Tags: vba, outlook

When I send an email (via Outlook, so I'm using VBA), if any of the recipient addresses' domains are not in a list of domains, I want to add " zsecure" to the subject line.

Here's my current code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim addrRecips As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim addrRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim arrDomain As Variant
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Dim recipDomain As String
    Dim subjSecure As String

    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
    Set addrRecips = Item.Recipients

    ' Set up the array
    arrDomain = Array("domain1.com", "domain2.com", "domain3.com", "domain4.net")

    For Each addrRecip In addrRecips
        Set pa = addrRecip.PropertyAccessor

        ' Get the domain from the current recipient's email address
        recipDomain = Split(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS), "@", 2, vbTextCompare)(1)
        Debug.Print recipDomain

        ' Check if the recipient's email domain is in the array of domains
        If IsInArray(recipDomain, arrDomain) = False Then
            Debug.Print "Recipient domain, " & recipDomain & ", is in array of domains"

            ' Current recipient's email domain is not in the list, so add " zsecure" to the subject
            subjSecure = Item.Subject & " zsecure"
            Item.Subject = subjSecure

            ' If any of the recipients' domains is not in the list, we can stop here and send the email
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

And when I try to send an email, "IsInArray" get highlighted (selected) and an error message box says "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined". As far as I can tell I'm properly initializing, populating and using the array, so I'm not seeing what's causing the error.

Comment: Can you please post IsInArray() function so that we can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very unambiguous - the function `IsInArray()` is not defined in your code, at least not in the code snippet that you posted.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. When I was researching to do this I saw IsInArray() used by several sources, which led me to believe that it was a pre-defined function in VBA. I found a source that defines that function and incorporated that into my code and it works fine now. Thanks again!